# Access control exception

Tags: java, database, derby

I tried to execute the server in my NetBeans 7.3.1 java project, but I got this:

```
    Sun Mar 26 15:48:04 EEST 2017 : DRDA_SecurityInstalled.I
Sun Mar 26 15:48:04 EEST 2017 : access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "localhost:1527" "listen,resolve")
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "localhost:1527" "listen,resolve")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:472)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:884)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkListen(SecurityManager.java:1131)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:374)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
    at javax.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.createServerSocket(ServerSocketFactory.java:231)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.NetworkServerControlImpl.createServerSocket(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.NetworkServerControlImpl.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.NetworkServerControlImpl$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.NetworkServerControlImpl.blockingStart(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.NetworkServerControlImpl.executeWork(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.drda.NetworkServerControl.main(Unknown Source)
```

I've been looking for the solution and I found one - change the permissons in `java.policy` file. Well, I did it:

```
// Standard extensions get all permissions by default


grant codeBase "file:${{java.home}}/*" { permission java.security.AllPermission;
};

// default permissions granted to all domains

grant {
        // Allows any thread to stop itself using the java.lang.Thread.stop()
        // method that takes no argument.
        // Note that this permission is granted by default only to remain
        // backwards compatible.
        // It is strongly recommended that you either remove this permission
        // from this policy file or further restrict it to code sources
        // that you specify, because Thread.stop() is potentially unsafe.
        // See the API specification of java.lang.Thread.stop() for more
        // information.
        permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "stopThread";

        // allows anyone to listen on dynamic ports
        permission java.net.SocketPermission "localhost:0", "listen";

        // "standard" properies that can be read by anyone

        permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.version", "read";
        permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.vendor", "read";
        permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.vendor.url", "read";
        permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.class.version", "read";
        permission java.util.PropertyPermission "os.name", "read";
        permission java.util.PropertyPermission "os.version", "read";
        permission java.util.PropertyPermission "os.arch", "read";
        permission java.util.PropertyPermission "file.separator", "read";
        permission java.util.PropertyPermission "path.separator", "read";
        permission java.util.PropertyPermission "line.separator", "read";

        permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.specification.version", "read";
        permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.specification.vendor", "read";
        permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.specification.name", "read";

        permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.vm.specification.version", "read";
        permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.vm.specification.vendor", "read";
        permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.vm.specification.name", "read";
        permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.vm.version", "read";
        permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.vm.vendor", "read";
        permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.vm.name", "read";
 permission java.net.SocketPermission "localhost:1527", "listen";// here I added this string that should resolve this problem
};
```

After those steps I've tried to push the server, but still thame exception is throwed. Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: any ideas?I'd be glad to resolve it...

Comment: https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.13/security/csecjavasecurity.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found few things that might help.

1. Use :
   *`permission java.net.SocketPermission "localhost:1527", "listen";`

   instead of : 

   `permission java.net.SocketPermission "localhost:0", "listen";`*
2. Make sure you are modifying the correct policy files in-case of multiple JREs present on your system.To verify this use :

   `System.out.println(System.getProperty(“java.home”));`
   Then make changes to :

   `{Above path}\lib\security\java.policy`